# Разбиение столбца ФИО на отдельные элементы sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью sql можно разбить строку ФИО на отдельные ее части.
Есть столбец, с ФИО моя задача в нем определить самое длинное имя, именно имя.
Например 'Иванов Иван Иванович.'

Не совсем понимаю как применить substring.

Спасибо.

Comment: надо учесть, что бывают еще двойные имена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  split_part(column, ' ', 1) as first_name, 
  split_part(column, ' ', 2) as middle_name,
  split_part(column, ' ', 3) as last_name 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: А Как вы применили substring?

Comment: @DarKsp если ответ решил ваш вопрос, поставьте галку слева от него (для всех ваших вопросов)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что у Вас таблица `user` и поле `full_name` и Имя в промежутке между пробелами,

тогда

```
SELECT substring(full_name from '\s+[^\s]+') As name FROM user;
```

Конечно не мешало бы сделать trim к тому же

```
SELECT trim(substring(full_name from '\s+[^\s]+')) as name FROM user;
```

Ну или использовать другую функцию

```
SELECT trim((regexp_split_to_array(full_name, E'\\s+'))[2] ) as name FROM user;
```

PS. Можно ещё позициями это вычислить